# How to expand Angular Material Tab to show Angular Grid data?

Tags: tabs, angular-material, angular8, angular-grid

I am using Angular 8 and want to show Angular Grid inside Angular Material Tab in following manner:-

```
<mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Request Flow">
            <div class="div-main">
                <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham grid-dimensions" [pagination]="true"
                    [gridOptions]="reqDetailGridOptions" [rowData]="reqDetailRowData" [columnDefs]="reqDetailColDef"
                    [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight" [paginationPageSize]=50 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
                </ag-grid-angular>
                <br />                
                <button class="button-internal">Add Subrequest</button>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

The issue is that even if data present in Angular Grid then also Angular Material Tab is not expanding to make Angular Grid visible. It is showing like below:-

[image]

However when I put Angular Grid outside Angular Material Tab then the grid is showing its full data.

I tried to use "dynamicHeight" property of "mat-tab-group" but it is of no use.

Please help here.

Comment: Did you try to give your class `div-main` position `relative`? Or maybe to set a width property on it.

Comment: easier to help if you share a MVCE stackblitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps worked for me:-

1. Added [dynamicHeight] = "true" to mat-tab-group.
2. Added following CSS:-

   .mat-tab-group{
       height: 100%;
   }
   .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
       flex-grow: 1;
   }

   .mat-tab-body {
       display: flex !important;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

Comment: I had to use all 4 of these statements, but with ::ng-deep as @Houssem Melliti indicated.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-body-wrapper { 
    flex-grow: 1; 
}
```

you have to override mat-tab-body-wrapper style with ::ng-deep